# An Object reference return from a Singleton Class is Thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

I want to return an object from a singleton class, that object is using by many threads and also two methods in the singleton class. Is it safe to return that object reference? Please see my sample

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                MyObject rv = Singleton.getInstance().get();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    System.out.println("THREAD 0 : " + rv.getCount());
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    Singleton.getInstance().update();
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() {
        MyObject rv = new MyObject(1, 1);
        hashmap.put(1, rv);
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private final HashMap<Integer, MyObject> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

    public MyObject get() {

        return hashmap.get(1);
    }

    public void update() {
        hashmap.get(1).setCount(hashmap.get(1).getCount() + 1);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyObject {
    int count;
    int id;

    MyObject(int id, int count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Err, no, why would you think that? An object is thread-safe if and only iff it is thread-safe. Singletons have nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: You made getInstance() synchronised, but whatever you do after you get the singleton instance isn't threadsafe. On the upside, I don't think it needs to be. I might be wrong about that though.

Comment: Do you have any reasons to use hashmap here? If not, drop it. You probably want to make the update() method synchronized as well, if you use it from different threads simultaneously, otherwise some update requests may be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the MyObject is used you need to protect access to the fields as well.

```
public enum Singleton { 
    INSTANCE;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private final Map<Integer, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized int getCount(int key) {
        MyObject mo = map.get(key);
        if (mo == null)
            return 1;
        return mo.getCount();
    }

    public synchronized void update(int key) {
        MyObject mo = map.get(key);
        if (mo == null)
            map.put(key, mo = new MyObject(1, 1));
        mo.incrementCount();
    }
}
```

On the MyObject class you would add a method

```
public void incrementCount() {
    count++;
}
```

Note: since you don't have direct access to the underlying MyObject, you don't need to add additional synchronization.

---

The reference to the object is thread safe, but none of the access outside the `synchronized` block is thread safe.

Note: there is no co-ordination between threads and one could finish before the other one starts.  Also incrementing a counter is much faster than printing to the console so you should see the counter jump quite a bit, in fact it might jump from 0 to 100, one line apart.
In fact you have it in the wrong place, you can do this instead.

```
public enum Singleton { 
    INSTANCE;

private Singleton() {
    hashmap.put(1, new MyObject(1, 1));
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

private final Map<Integer, MyObject> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

public synchronized MyObject get() {
    // safe is all you need to do is read one value.
    return hashmap.get(1);
}

public synchronized void update() {
    hashmap.get(1).setCount(hashmap.get(1).getCount() + 1);
}
}
```

or even simpler

```
public enum Singleton { 
    INSTANCE;
    private final MyObject myObj = new MyObject(1, 1);

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public synchronized MyObject get() {
        // safe is all you need to do is read one value.
        return myObj;
    }

    public synchronized void update() {
        myObject.setCount(myObject.getCount() + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this threadsafe when `Singleton.getInstance().get()` returns the MyObject instance which may happily be modified unsynchronized by any threads that like to do so? I don't know why my answer was downvoted, but you need the synchronisation on MyObject.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch The implied use case, is to read one value out of the MyObject and for this you don't need another synchronized and the one of get() provides a memory barrier.

Comment: From the question: _that object is using by many threads and also two methods in the singleton class_. It may be in this sample that the only use of the returned object is for using it's `getCount()`. But if this a sample demonstratin a bigger problem, then you might run into trouble.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the MyObject threadsafe, as an istance of this class is used by different threads (notice the synchronized methods:

```
public class MyObject {
    int count;
    int id;

    MyObject(int id, int count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public synchronized void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public synchronized void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but this won't help any of the other code thread safe, e.g. `hashmap.get(1).setCount(hashmap.get(1).getCount() + 1);` is broken in a number of ways even with your changes.